# how can I migrate my azure devops repository from using source control editor to using the git style control?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure, devops

I'm not even sure what to search for but I'm been hunting for this information for a while.

I have two clients using Azure Devops, and currently the only way I can access the repos is thru visual studio's Source Control Editor or directly on visualstudio.com sites in a browser.

I'm used to using visual studio with the git repo style, under Team Explorer in local git repositories.  I can see the connection in team explorer but I can't they aren't in the local git repositories, making handling branching more difficult.

I want to keep everything in azure devops where it current sits but just change it to the github system, but I'm not sure exactly how to do this.

I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-TFVC?view=azure-devops but I am not sure the code is under TFS or not. (I know tfs changed it's name to azure devops or at least I believe it did.)  Either way, the document doesn't help me as the only drop down it shows only displays the name of the repository.

I'm an admin on one of these sites, so if it's a permission problem, I should be able to adjust it at least for one client, but I'm not sure which permission it is.  Looking thru them nothing struck me as an obvious problem.

I'm not sure which direction to go.

Edit: figured out the problem.  We don't have top level rights to the organization in the repo.  It was created by someone else ages ago, and they didn't pass on organization level permissions.  Only solution I have is to recreate the repository as we're using a free license to azure repositories.

Comment: If you don't know which SCM you want to migrate from, how are we supposed to provide guidance?

Comment: @IInspectable very good point.  Even a tip on how to figure out which SCM I'm using would be really helpful though.    All I can tell you is that I'm using visual studio, and Azure Devops.  With the current clients, I see Azure Devops in the upper corner when I am looking at it on thru the browser.  When I look at it thru visual studio, I see the files thru team explorer but it gives me Source Control Explorer.

Comment: @IInspectable   I don't see the option to add a branch. I don't see the option to Clone from this repository either.  If I want to reload this repository, I have to use "Get latest version" from SCE.  (not solution explorer).